# CodeIgniter REST API calling nonexistent method

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest, backbone.js

Using Phil Sturgeon's [Codeigniter REST SERVER](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver), I've set up a basic REST server to interact with a Backbone application. The issue is that whenever the applcation tries to make a DELETE request to the proper URI (for instance, api/object/7 where 7 is the ID number in question), REST returns a 404 Not Found error. A bit of digging revealed that it was trying to reach the nonexistint 7_delete within the controller instead of calling index_delete as it should.

I've checked the requests, and they're routing to the correct URL; I've also checked that there are no custom routes set up which would interfere and there are none. Suggestions?

EDIT: For more detail, the Backbone routing is set up like this:

```
urlRoot: 'api/objective/',
```

The Objective controller in CI meanwhile is set up like this:

```
class Objective extends REST_Controller {

  /**
   *  Respond to a POST request;
   *  - If given an ID, update an existing record
   *  - If given no ID, create a new record
   */
  public function index_post() {
    // code here...
  }

  /**
   *  Delete an existing record from a passed URL
   */
  public function index_delete($id) {
    // Code here...
  }

  /**
   *  Get a single record
   */
  public function index_get($id) {
    // Code here...
  }

  /**
   *  Get the full objectives list
   */
  public function index_get() {
    // Code here...
  }
}
```

This is close to the example provided in the original example file. The CI routing has nothing set up however.

Comment: Could you provide some detailed code?

Comment: @moberemk how you have setup your routing in CI & Backbone ?

Comment: I've added some detail to the above post to answer your questions.

Answer (score -1):

maybe it easy when you use url like this http://example.com/api/objective/deletecontent/id/7

```
    public function deletecontent_get() {
        if(!$this->get('id')) {$this->response(null,400)}
          $run = $this->some_model->delete_content_by_id($this->get('id));
          if($run) $this->response(true,200);
          else $this->response(null,304);
    }
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it completely negates the point of using a REST API by not making use of stuff like the DELETE method instead of simple GET URLs. Good try though.